# What is an example of Licklider’s idea of man-machine symbiosis in constructing information systems?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am trying to understand Licklider’s idea of man-machine symbiosis in the real world, does anyone know of any real world examples of the use of a man-machine symbiosis?

Would it be correct to say that safety critical systems such as an aircraft flight control system is an example of this, due to it fitting into the following criteria in [Licklider's ideas](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/medg/people/psz/Licklider.html):

> The main aims are 1) to let computers facilitate formulative thinking
>   as they now facilitate the solution of formulated problems, and 2) to
>   enable men and computers to cooperate in making decisions and
>   controlling complex situations without inflexible dependence on
>   predetermined programs.

Comment: his ideas are asserted by some to have indirectly partly inspired the WWW! anyway though examples are rife in the modern world with cell phones, wearable computing eg google glass, oculus rift glasses, motion capture in video games, etc! see also the topic of "cybernetics"...

Comment: Would the Turing Machine be an example of Man-Machine symbiosis?